# How to generate this simulation of rotating circles in 3D?

Tags: graphics, animation, generative-art

I saw this beautiful, hypnotic set of concentric circles rotating in 3D around the origin.

[image]

I thought I could produce the same on Mathematica, but terribly failed. So far this is what I tried:

```
Graphics[Table[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Lighter@Hue[0.42 + 0.1 r], Circle[{0, 0}, r]}, {r, 0, 10, 0.5}], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

The above code produces a nice set of circles. I used `RotateTransform` inside `Graphics3D` too, but it says `CircleBox` is not a `Graphics3D` primitive. I do not know how to implement further.

Any idea or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Circle`s are really 2D objects, unfortunately you can't use them on `Graphics3D` like that.

You can start with this:

```
Table[
  Graphics3D[
   Table[{Hue[h],
     Rotate[Tube@Table[h {Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/50}],
      u h, {0, 0, 1}]},
    {h, 1/20, 1, 1/20}],
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, ViewPoint -> Front, 
   ViewAngle -> 30 Degree, Boxed -> False, Background -> Black],
  {u, 0, 5 Pi, Pi/10}] // ListAnimate
```

[image]

This just creates your rings as 3D `Tube`s, sets lighting as intended and rotates these rings.

Comment: +1, that is nice! I should have realised `Tube`s are the objects to be used, thanks. I will wait for more submissions until I accept this.

Comment: Is it a mere coincidence that your profile pic looks very relevant for this question?

Comment: @expikx Heh, it's purely coincidental. :)

Comment: Haha, I'm just kidding :)